# Getting iPhone Documents Directory in TestCases

Tags: sqlite, ios5, xcode4, testcase, sentestingkit

I'm running test cases which uses sqlite database to test my code on iPhone simulator using default SenTestingkit,
when i try to get the home directory using either of the following ways

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

or

```
NSString *home = NSHomeDirectory();
```

i got a wrong path that points to the following bath

```
/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1
```

and i couldn't create the sqlite database,
any idea how to get the right path in the Test cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :)

first I had to detect whether i'm in TestCase or running project using NSClassFromString for the SenTest Class then construct the path according to each case

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"SenTest") == nil) {
        // Running project -> path inside the Document folder
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:KDatabaseName];
    } else {
        // Test case -> path inside "UnitTests" folder in the project directory
        NSString *directory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
        path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UnitTests/"];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:KDatabaseName];
    }
```

Comment: I came to the same problem. Is there any way we can force the test case run to use the same doc directory as when running the app. I have some important values and files to be read (like app activation).

Comment: NSClassFromString(@"SenTest") returns nil in the app target AND the unit test target. I presume the name has changed now

Comment: .. change @"SenTest" to @"XCTestCase" and the code now works as intended