# How to access NSDocumentDirectory in unit tests (OCUnit)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ocunit

I'm trying to run my app in OCUnit environment. It uses a sqlite database and I'm having it in the app's documents folder.

However when running from the tests, the path for the database is set to:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Documents/Test.sqlite
```

While the same code gives me a path of

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/34536EFB-005A-44A1-AD99-07D6B9F6888B/Documents/Test.sqlite
```

when I run it on the simulator.

How can I use NSDocumentDirectory in my tests and get what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application target is not the same as the test target, that's why you get different paths.

When using OCUnit you can get the test `NSBundle` like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"myResource" ofType:@"someType"];
```

You have to add the database to the resources of the test target and use it accordingly.

Or you can build the path like this (taken from this [OS Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882131/719656)):

```
// Test case -> path inside "UnitTests" folder in the project directory
NSString *directory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
NSString *path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UnitTests/"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.sqlite"];
```